# JQuery Toggle Version Differences 1.4.1 vs Newer

Tags: jquery, toggle

In Jquery 1.4.1 the code below works as expected. However when I try to upgrade to 1.4.4 or 1.5.1 I get some weirdness.
It's a treeview, where you click on a +/- and it expands or collapses.
When I try to do a new version of JQuery the expand/collapse of a child also triggers the parent to fire too.
it is based on this, http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and/or need to change to make this work with newer versions of JQuery?

```
$('div.tree div').live("click", function() {
                    var o = $(this);
                    o.children('div').toggle();
                    o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');                

});

div.tree div.parent
{
    cursor: pointer !important;
    background: transparent url(../../Images/plus.gif) no-repeat top left;
    font-size: 12px;
}
div.tree div.expanded
{
    background: transparent url(../../Images/minus.gif) no-repeat top left;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without the HTML you used as well, but I think your misinterpreting the logic behind a jQuery selection. When you do the following:

```
o.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');
```

You are selecting all div.parent elements inside of all div.tree elements. So naturally if you are 5 children deep and call this function everything marked as parent would be toggled. Unless I misunderstand how you set up your HTML markup

Comment: <div class="tree" id="treeview" >
  <div class="parent expanded" id="fou">text
     <div class="parent expanded" id="fou2">text2
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: it would seem you are correct, how do I toggle only the div I'm in?

Comment: A couple different ways. 1) Have the class have the level number like: <div class="parent level1">text <div class="parent level2">more</div></div>, 2) select like: $("div.tree > div > div...") however many levels you want to go down. I recomend the first one. you can get the classes and see what level the div is in dynamically, or select all at level 2, etc.

Comment: since I have the div from var o = $(this); it is already selected. I tried o.toggleClass('expanded'); to no avail.

Comment: If I keep all the code the same and add return false; in the function it works

Comment: have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question